# Deletion of flagged comments

Tags: support, comment, flagging, deletion

Suppose I flag a comment, and the user subsequently deletes the comment before the flag is resolved. Do the moderators still see my flag?

(I tried searching previously asked meta questions, but could only find questions about flags *resulting in* the deletion of comments.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Any comment flag is resolved as helpful when a comment is deleted, unless the flag has aged away or the moderators declined the flag prior to deleting the comment.

If you feel that something might be still off, you can find the post in your flagging history and raise a moderator flag alerting us to a problematic comment.